# Finding Duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find duplicates in a non-traditional scenario:

Sample Table:

```
id1  | id2
-----+-----
ABC  | DEF
DEF  | ABC
```

I only want to retain one of these rows, as these ids show a connection to each other.  What is the most elegant way to filter out the second row?

Comment: Can you pleas add the tag of database used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the dups, but only retain those where id1 is smaller than id2.

An EXISTS can be used for that.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM YourTable t2
  WHERE t2.id1 = t.id2 
    AND t2.id2 = t.id1
    AND t2.id1 > t2.id2
);
```

Comment: I updated the table above, the ids can be varchar, and do not need to be greater or less than

Comment: Actually, that doesn't matter much.  'DEF' is alphabetically bigger than 'ABC'.

Comment: But if you need the one with a lowest ID (first inserted) then another SQL would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select id1, id2
from t
where id1 < id2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id1 = t.id2 and t2.id2 = t.id1
                 );
```

Note:  This assumes that `id1` and `id2` are never equal, although you can adjust the logic for that.

Also, if there can be duplicates in the data (apart from "flips"), then you'll want `select distinct` or a similar mechanism to remove them.

Comment: I updated the table above, the ids can be varchar, and do not need to be greater or less than

Comment: @lilerer . . . This will work on strings, or any type.

Answer (score 0):

Using `case` and `distinct`

```
select distinct 
      case when id1 <= id2 then id1 else id2 end id1
    , case when id1 <= id2 then id2 else id1 end id2
from t
```

It will revert columns in some rows. Provided  (3,4) is considered equivalent to (4,3) it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I updated the table above, the ids can be varchar, and do not need to be greater or less than

Comment: @lilerer,  It still works provided `DEF  | ABC` is considered equivalent to `ABC  | DEF` .